# Is it possible to call the drawer menu as a single line of code?

Tags: java, android, drawer

I have a code for drawer-menu:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.drMain:
                Intent intentMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentMain);
                break;

            case R.id.drDiarys:
                Intent intentDiarys = new Intent(this, Diarys.class);
                startActivity(intentDiarys);
                break;

            case R.id.drFav:
                Intent intentFav = new Intent(this, Favorites.class);
                startActivity(intentFav);
                break;

            case R.id.drSendStory:
                Intent intentSendStory = new Intent(this, SendStory.class);
                startActivity(intentSendStory);
                break;

            case R.id.drTg:
                Intent intentTg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/joinchat/FAPWlBHEWo2oLKXcpEeN4A"));
                startActivity(intentTg);
                break;

            case R.id.drVk:
                Intent intentVk = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://vk.com/unspecific"));
                startActivity(intentVk);
                break;

            case R.id.drSettings:
                Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(intentSettings);
                break;

            case R.id.drAbout:
                Intent intentAbout = new Intent(this, Help.class);
                startActivity(intentAbout);
                break;

            case R.id.drChat:
                Intent chat = new Intent(this, Chat.class);
                startActivity(chat);
                break;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawer.closeDrawers();
            }
        }, 100);
        return true;
    }
```

And I have 10+ activitys where I'm using this code. **I would put this code at another java class (for example Drawer.class) and run it in the right activitys (for example with `getDrawerMenu`).**

Is it possible? The purpose of this is to reduce the number of lines of code.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have to just pass right number of arguments in the method.

Comment: Can you make an example pls?

Comment: Okay, I've marked your question as Favorite, I'll do and update it here.

Comment: Thanx, waiting.

Comment: you can create seperate common method and pass selected item id and context to it and call it.